# Building cassandra in local machine

Tags: eclipse, ant, cassandra

Getting below error when I tried to build cassandra in my local box.

```
build-project:
     [echo] apache-cassandra: /Users/sn1/cassandra-codeBase/cassandra/build.xml
    [javac] Compiling 41 source files to /Users/sn1/cassandra-codeBase/cassandra/build/classes/thrift
    [javac] error: error reading /Users/sn1/cassandra-codeBase/cassandra/build/lib/jars/core-3.1.1.jar; cannot read zip file
    [javac] Note: /Users/sn1/cassandra-codeBase/cassandra/interface/thrift/gen-java/org/apache/cassandra/thrift/Cassandra.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
/Users/sn1/cassandra-codeBase/cassandra/build.xml:675: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: can you post compiler error output

Answer (score 0):

You should have the core-3.1.1.jar in the /Users/sn1/cassandra-codeBase/cassandra/build/lib/jars/ directory.

Comment: If OP doesn't have the file in the right place, which is what appears to be the case, it's a solution, @DenisErmolin

Comment: Yes. Actually I found that root cause. core-3.1.1.jar was corrupted, once I cleared the jar file from path. It downloaded the proper jar.

Comment: @hd1 SO isn't the correct place to exercise the Socratic method, please rephrase your answer into.. an answer.

Comment: @tysonjh are you happy now?